# Remove Add to Cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove WooCommerce add to cart button(s) using the following code:

```
function WC() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
    return WooCommerce::instance();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I’m using newspaper theme and have tried editing `WC-template-hooks.php` as suggested in some threads.

Comment: "*but it didn’t work*" - What does this mean? Are you receiving any errors? Is the cart still there? Please provide enough details

Comment: Not getting any error but the 'Add to Cart" button didn't go away.

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes and missing parameters in your provided code.

Try the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'remove_all_wc_add_to_cart' );
function remove_all_wc_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: I have added the above code in functions.php of child theme but Add to cart is not going. I have also tried the code in woocommerce.php but no luck. Could you please suggest the plugin file to edit. Thanks

Comment: If Add to cart is not going, it's because of your theme customizations, an additional 3rd Party plugin or because of your own code customizations… This code is tested and works on WooCommerce Storefront theme and WordPress default themes… if the theme is the culprit you should search and ask in the theme authors support pages.